# Unicorn / Capistrano, Post deploy Unicorn workers on new PID, app not refreshing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, unicorn

So I've setup unicorn to restart post deploy on capistrano 3. It tells me it restarted OK, it has new PID's for workers, but when I refresh the app no change?

- I did a simple test and changed a small item in the view.
- If I do a "restart" on the server, it doesn't pickup the change.
- If I manually stop / start unicorn on the server it picks up the change.

> INFO [528d1d0f] Finished in 0.023 seconds with exit status 0
>   (successful).
>            INFO [a114fafd] Running /usr/bin/env sudo /etc/init.d/unicorn_salescrm_production restart on
>   salescrm.mydomain.com
>           DEBUG [a114fafd] Command: ( RBENV_ROOT=/home/deploy/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.1.0 /usr/bin/env sudo
>   /etc/init.d/unicorn_salescrm_production restart )
>           DEBUG [a114fafd]        reloaded OK

```
    deploy@ip-172-31-10-178:~/salescrm_production/current$ ps aux | grep unicorn
    deploy    6748  0.6  0.8 714104 136204 ?       Sl   05:00   0:10 unicorn master -D -c /home/deploy/salescrm_production/current/config/unicorn.rb -E production
    deploy    7741  0.2  0.8 720872 137472 ?       Sl   05:23   0:00 unicorn worker[1] -D -c /home/deploy/salescrm_production/current/config/unicorn.rb -E production
    deploy    7747  0.3  0.9 723708 140324 ?       Sl   05:23   0:00 unicorn worker[0] -D -c /home/deploy/salescrm_production/current/config/unicorn.rb -E production
    deploy    7750  0.4  0.9 727468 144300 ?       Sl   05:23   0:00 unicorn worker[2] -D -c /home/deploy/salescrm_production/current/config/unicorn.rb -E production
    deploy    7755  0.3  0.8 717292 134252 ?       Sl   05:23   0:00 unicorn worker[3] -D -c /home/deploy/salescrm_production/current/config/unicorn.rb -E production
    deploy    7857  0.0  0.0   8112   928 pts/0    S+   05:27   0:00 grep unicorn


deploy@ip-172-31-10-178:~/salescrm_production/current$ ps aux | grep unicorn
deploy    6748  0.6  0.8 714104 136232 ?       Sl   05:00   0:10 unicorn master -D -c /home/deploy/salescrm_production/current/config/unicorn.rb -E production
deploy    7977  2.0  0.8 715132 131960 ?       Sl   05:27   0:00 unicorn worker[3] -D -c /home/deploy/salescrm_production/current/config/unicorn.rb -E production
deploy    7980  2.0  0.8 715132 131964 ?       Sl   05:27   0:00 unicorn worker[0] -D -c /home/deploy/salescrm_production/current/config/unicorn.rb -E production
deploy    7986  2.0  0.8 715132 131960 ?       Sl   05:27   0:00 unicorn worker[1] -D -c /home/deploy/salescrm_production/current/config/unicorn.rb -E production
deploy    7990  2.0  0.8 715132 131960 ?       Sl   05:27   0:00 unicorn worker[2] -D -c /home/deploy/salescrm_production/current/config/unicorn.rb -E production
deploy    8005  0.0  0.0   8112   928 pts/0    S+   05:28   0:00 grep unicorn
deploy@ip-172-31-10-178:~/salescrm_production/current$
```

Comment: What signal does this `/etc/init.d/unicorn_salescrm_production` use for `restart`?. For example, if you set `preload = true`, you should use `USR2` instead of `HUP` for restart. http://unicorn.bogomips.org/SIGNALS.html

Comment: Awesome that worked :) Can you add as an answer and I will accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What signal does this `/etc/init.d/unicorn_salescrm_production` use for restart?. For example, if you set `preload = true`, you should use `USR2` instead of `HUP` for restart. http://unicorn.bogomips.org/SIGNALS.html